# Is the shape of a fusee really a hyperbola?

Tags: geometry, functions, analytic-geometry

It turns out that the shape of the cross-section of a fusee (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fusee_(horology)) is given by an equation of the form $y = a / \sqrt{x + b}$. I have read from many sources that the shape of a fusee is a hyperbola. Is the shape of the graph of this equation really a hyperbola? I mean this equation can be transformed into $xy^2 + by^2 - a = 0$ which is a cubic equation. Wouldn't the equation of a hyperbola be a quadratic equation?

If this equation describes a hyperbola, does it mean that $y = 1 / \sqrt{x}$ describes a hyperbola too? After all, we are just making $a = 1$ and $b = 0$.

Comment: You're right, this isn't a hyperbola. Do you have a source for this claim about $y = \frac{a}{\sqrt{x+b}}$?

Comment: The equation is derived in Chapter 10, History and Mathematical Analysis of the Fusee in the book The Clockwork Universe, edited by Klaus Maurice and Otto Mayr. The chapter itself is written by Peter Honig. He first derives an integral equation which can be solved to get the equation. The way he solves it in the book isn't entirely satisfactory. Basically he makes an assumption about the form of the solution and then finds the values for the parameters. But it is straightforward to solve the integral equation directly and when you do it, you'll get an equation of the form $y=a/\sqrt{x+b}$.

Comment: Okay, well, as you said that isn't a hyperbola!

Comment: @russell.price  It would help if you typed in the integral equation.....

Comment: @WillJagy It is $rm \frac{2 \pi}{t}\int_0^z{r dZ} = T$. Here, $r$ and $z$ are the variables. Everything else is a constant.

Comment: @Qiaochu Yuan Thank you!